# I want to select rows from two tables having same column name using single select query

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables. Both tables has the same columns with same column names as well. Suppose both tables has 4 records each. I want to select the 8 rows from both table using only a single select statement without using Union or Union All.

Comment: Provide sample inputs for two tables and expected outputs...

Answer (score 1):

Use UNION

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2;
```

Comment: thanks for reply. actually I said same to interviewer but he said don't use union it will have two different select statement and then it will join the records. so don't know how to achieve this. is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking something like this

```
select coalesce(i1.col1,c1.col1) as col1 from table1 i1
    full join table2 c1
on i1.col1 = c1.col1
```

Comment: It seems to me that your code does a UNION not a UNION ALL, because matching values will not get repeated. Doesn't it?

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I think this is correct statement. let me try this one.

Comment: @KannanKandasamy . yes it is working as per requirement. thanks a lot